# Laravel Filament PHP 3 not able to update records keep getting value exists with Unique attribute

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am going through a tutorial and have watched the same video a few times to see if I had incorrect syntax on my form, but to me it looked ok. But when I hit 'edit' and then click save changes I get an error that the value already exists. This is happening on each of the forms I created.

I'm able to create a new form and I can edit a product if I change the product name and sku, which defeats the purpose, but it does record the changes in the database so I know the update functionality is working.

Here is the form code for the product:

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Group::make()
                ->schema([
                    Section::make()
                    ->schema([
                        TextInput::make('name')
                            ->required()
                            ->live(onBlur:true)
                            ->unique()
                            ->afterStateUpdated(function(string $operation, $state, Forms\Set $set){
                                    if($operation!=='create'){
                                        return;
                                    }
                                $set('slug', Str::slug($state));

                            }),
                        TextInput::make('slug')
                            ->disabled()
                            ->dehydrated()
                            ->required()
                            ->unique(Product::class,'slug',ignoreRecord:true),
                        MarkdownEditor::make('description')
                            ->columnSpan('full')
                ])->columns(2),
                Section::make('Pricing & Inventory')
                ->schema([
                  TextInput::make('sku')
                  ->label('SKU (Stock Keeping Unit)')
                  ->required()
                    ->unique(),
                  TextInput::make('price')
                    ->numeric()
                    ->rules(['regex:/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{0,2})?$/'])
                    ->required(),
                  TextInput::make('quantity')
                    ->numeric()
                    ->minValue(0)
                    ->maxValue(100)
                    ->required(),
                  Select::make('type')
                    ->options([
                        'downloadable' => ProductTypeEnum::DOWNLOADABLE->value,
                        'deliverable' => ProductTypeEnum::DELIVERABLE->value

                    ])->required()
                ])->columns(2)
                ]),
            Group::make()
            ->schema([
                Section::make('Status')
                    ->schema([
                        Toggle::make('is_visible')
                        ->label("Visibility")
                        ->helperText('Enable or disable product visibility')
                        ->default(true),

                        Toggle::make('is_featured')
                            ->label("Featured")
                            ->helperText('Enable or disable product featured status'),
                        DatePicker::make('published_at')
                            ->label('Avalability')
                            ->default(now())

                    ]),
                Section::make('Image')
                    ->schema([
                        FileUpload::make('image')
                            ->directory('form-attachements')
                            ->preserveFilenames()
                            ->image()
                            ->imageEditor()
                    ])->collapsible(),
                Section::make('Associations')
                ->schema([
                  Select::make('brand_id')
                    ->relationship('brand','name')
                ]),
            ])
            ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I did find that if you use

```
->unique(ignoreRecord: true),
```

It seems to work. Odd in the tutorial, it doesn't show that, and it seems to work for the presenter.